# What kind of microscope should be used to view biological structures (such as spores) roughly 5 µm in length?

Tags: mycology, microscopy

I would like to be able to identify genera of fungi based on the shape, size, and colour of spores. So the requirements are:

- Must be able to view a 5 micrometre object clearly with reasonable resolution
- Must be true colour
- Must facilitate the measurement of an object within reasonable accuracy (500 nanometres would be nice)
- Should be inexpensive (\$100-\$400) <sup>*fingers crossed*</sup>
- Bonus: Be able to take photos

What type of microscope do I need? What magnification/resolution? Is there a good rule of thumb relating size of object with magnification?

How do I find and purchase a decent microscope after defining my requirements? Any tips?

Blue light is ~450 nm, so does that mean I will not get very good resolution?

(For the sake of context: I have absolutely no formal experience in biology, but I have recently taken an amateur interest in mycology and might enrol in an undergraduate course as part of my degree at some point.)

Comment: From Wikipedia:

"With an optical microscope having a high numerical aperture and using oil immersion, the best possible resolution is 200 nm corresponding to a magnification of around 1200×."

So, I searched for 1000x optical microscopes and  found a [AmScope 40x-1000x](http://www.amazon.com/AmScope-40x-1000x-Widefield-Biological-Microscope/dp/B004UNFSYG/ref=pd_sbs_indust_2) on Amazon. Has anybody used this brand? Will this be sufficient?

Comment: Ooh, this one takes photos: [OMAX 40X-2000X Digital Binocular Biological Compound Microscope with Built-in 3.0MP USB Camera and Double Layer Mechanical Stage](http://www.amazon.com/OMAX-40X-2000X-Biological-Microscope-Mechanical/dp/B004RZXINU/ref=pd_sbs_indust_4) Is OMAX any good?

Comment: In this price range, I would avoid anything with very high magnifications > 600x or so. You'll find it very difficult to get enough contrast to see any details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a good question, but if you want to get a good understanding of the issues you raise with it, then you really ought to consider spending some time reading this [optical microscope primer](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/). In my opinion, you need not bother with taking an undergraduate course at a physical university. As an intro to biology (which is not really necessary if all you want to do is look at small things in a microscope and understand what you're seeing), you might want to consider enrolling in [this free class](https://www.edx.org/press/eric-lander-secret-of-life), but if all you want to do is look at small things and have a basic understanding of what you're seeing, I think all you need to do is read the primer.

If it was me, I'd read at least some of the primer before investing the money in a microscope. Otherwise you're just taking a blind leap of faith from someone's (perhaps biased) suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Kevin F, if I was you, I'd take a bit of training before buying something or even trying. Biology teachers or staff from the university are usually happy to provide you with a microscope to test something, so just ask. If you want a resolution that high, there are a lot of adjustments to do, commonly referred to as "Köhler illumination", because otherwise you won't get a nice picture.

To answer your question, you can basically forget microscopes at that price range for this resolution, let alone the ability to take photos. You would have to spend >$1000 to get something good enough. As in photography, this is largely due to the lenses. I don't have much experience with fungi, but you might want to have a phase contrast microscope to be able to see the specimens properly. You can buy microscopes with have a port for a DSLR camera, with which I've made good experiences.

For a 5 µm object, you could use a $60 \times$ lens (which, together with a $10 \times$ ocular makes a magnification of $600\times$), or even a $100 \times$ lens, when you want to resolve surface structures, but no idea, if the latter really works with your specimens, so you'd have to test that before buying.

So: First, get a bit of formal training, as suggested by Kevin F. Then, try it yourself without buying, and try it with your own specimens! Then, save money and buy. :-)

Comment: Agree 100%. Cheap lenses will just give blurry and distorted images. Beware of promises of 1000x, and color camera for $200... you will just be disappointed. The ideal would be going for something like the [Zeiss Primo Star](http://microscopy.zeiss.com/microscopy/en_de/products/light-microscopes/primo-star.html#inpagetabs-1) which goes for around 1500-2000€.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I just wanted to say that before reading your suggestion of taking a look at my university's microscopes before buying one I had thought about the same thing and have been just told today by a lady at the university that I would need consent for research from a professor for that.